# Not Required in Pydantic's Base Models

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic, typing

Im trying to accept data from an API and then validate the response structure with a Pydantic base model. However, I have the case where sometimes some fields will not come included in the response, while sometimes they do. The problem is, when I try to validate the structure, Pydantic starts complaining about those fields being "missing" even though they can be missing sometimes. I really don't understand how to define a field as "missible". The docs mention that a field that is just defined as a name and a type is considered this way, but I haven't had any luck

This is a simple example of what I'm trying to accomplish

```py
# Response: {a: 1, b: "abc", c: ["a", "b", "c"]}
response: dict = json.loads(request_response)

# Pydantic Base Model
from pydantic import BaseModel
class Model(BaseModel):
   a: int
   b: str
   c: List[str]
   d: float

# Validating 
Model(**response)

# Return: ValidationError - Missing "d" field
```

How do I make it so that "d" doesnt cause the validation to throw an error? I have tried to switch "d" to `d: Optional[float]` and `d: Optional[float] = 0.0`, but nothing works.

Thanks!

Comment: I am able to get it working if I use either of your suggestions

Comment: Oh interesting. So if you just add Optional, it allows you to not pass the "d" parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @python_user said, both your suggestions work.

Admittedly, the behavior of `typing.Optional` for Pydantic fields is poorly documented. Perhaps because it is assumed to be obvious. I personally don't find it obvious because `Optional[T]` is just equivalent to `Union[T, None]` (or `T | None` in the new notation).

Annotating a field with any other union of types, while omitting a default value will result in the field being required. But if you annotate with a union that includes `None`, the field automatically receives the `None` default value. Kind of inconsistent, but that is the way it is.

However, the question is ultimately what you want your model fields to be. What value should be assigned to field `d`, if it is not set explicitly? Should it be `None` or should it be some default `float` value? (like e.g. `0.`) If `None` is fine, then you can use `Optional[float]` or `float | None`, and you don't need to specify the default value. (Specifying `Optional[float] = None` is equivalent.) If you want any other default value, you'll need to specify it accordingly, e.g. `d: float = 0.0`; but in that case `None` would be an **invalid** value for that field.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError


class Model(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: str
    c: list[str]
    d: float | None  # or typing.Optional[float]
    e: float = 0.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Model.parse_obj({
        "a": 1,
        "b": "abc",
        "c": ["a", "b", "c"],
    }), "\n")
    try:
        Model.parse_obj({
            "a": 1,
            "b": "abc",
            "c": ["a", "b", "c"],
            "e": None,
        })
    except ValidationError as e:
        print(e)
```

Output:

```
a=1 b='abc' c=['a', 'b', 'c'] d=None e=0.0 

1 validation error for Model
e
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. I agree with you, when reading the docs this was kind of confusing

Comment: Just to add a referenc to the Pydantic official documentation Note on this very issue: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#required-fields. Quote: "In Pydantic V1, fields annotated with Optional or Any would be given an implicit default of None even if no default was explicitly specified. This behavior has changed in Pydantic V2, and there are no longer any type annotations that will result in a field having an implicit default value."